# How does an XSS script get executed?

Tags: xss

For example,

```
http://testsite.test/<script>alert("TEST");</script>
```

I know that browsers either send a request for the url if it contains only domain and resource path. If there is a query string, it gets sent by GET method. But how exactly is a script executed in the client's browser?

And why would anyone "enable" XSS?

I'm learning XSS, so please help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a very basic example, say you have a form where you ask for your user's name. Then on the next page, you (as the application developer) write "Hello, [anything the user entered]". The problem is that if the user entered something like `<script>alert(1)</script>` for his name, this would be printed in a vulnerable page as is, and run in the browser. This is called reflected xss, and this is only the very tip of the iceberg, for example your users might store their real name in a database and a query on a different page might list user names, which may also contain javascript which in this case would be run in a different user's browser.

The solution btw is output encoding, which in practice means replacing certain characters with safe ones, like < or > with &lt; and &gt; so that when the script tag is written, it won't be executed (but this is just a small portion of html encoding, sometimes a different one is needed).

So the point is that XSS is not deliberately enabled by a developer, quite the opposite, everybody wants to avoid it. It's a vulnerability of the code. However, sometimes it is not that straightforward, especially for people not being aware of secure coding practices.

Please note that there is *much* more to XSS than I have mentioned here, both on the how it can manifest itself and the how you can prevent it side.

Comment: So there is no foolproof method to prevent XSS? An attacker can always improvise?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by foolproof. If all output is always properly encoded (ie. the appropriate encoding is used for all dynamic output),
 it is impossible to exploit XSS. However, every developer that writes UI code must be aware, and that's close to impossible to get right 100%
 of the time. There can be additional measures like input validation that help to some extent, and in general it's mostly about processes around development, the SDLC basically. (Also I fixed my character replacement (html encoding) example, I wrote my answer on a phone and didn't see it appeared incorrect.)